# Laravel Dusk fails to assert seeing a text which is visible in the screenshot (using whenAvailable for modal)

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk, browser-testing

I have written a Laravel Dusk test. I am trying to assert whether some text is visible after the modal is open. So, I am using the `whenAvailable` method. But it fails while I can see the text in the screenshot.

```
$browser->press('@finish-setup-button')
        ->whenAvailable('#modal-payment-info', function ($modal) use($paymentInfo) {
            $modal->assertSee(html_entity_decode(__('account_setup.payment')))
                  ->type('name', $paymentInfo->name)
                  ->type('iban', $paymentInfo->iban)
                  ->type('bic', $paymentInfo->bic)
                  ->press('@subscribe-button');
        });
```

I am getting the following message:

> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1) Tests\Browser\RegistrationTest::testRegistration Did not see
>   expected text [Payment] within element [body #modal-payment-info].
>   Failed asserting that false is true.

Screenshot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a workaround. I added a pause of 1 second and it works fine.

```
$browser->press('@finish-setup-button')
        ->whenAvailable('#modal-payment-info', function ($modal) use($paymentInfo) {
            $modal->pause(1000)
                  ->assertSee(html_entity_decode(__('account_setup.payment')))
                  ->type('name', $paymentInfo->name)
                  ->type('iban', $paymentInfo->iban)
                  ->type('bic', $paymentInfo->bic)
                  ->press('@subscribe-button');
        });
```

Comment: waiting a set amount of time is bad practice. What if that element happens to show after 1.1 seconds?

Comment: @rob There is an answer from James Anelay and he suggests using `->waitForText()` instead of `->pause(1000)`. I have not tested it yet as the answer came 2 years after my question and I am no longer working on the project. So, you can try using `waitForText()`.

Answer (score 5):

I just came across the same issue, I assume it's simply not there when the assertion is tested, but then appears by the time the screenshot is taken.

Rather than add a 1-second delay you can also use `->waitForText()` which will remove most unnessacary waiting time.